# Java's "UserContext" equivalent in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing REST services using Django Rest Framework. I want to keep some of the values like Language Code, AppId in a global variable (not static) and access it where ever I want. This may change for every request. In Java we call it as "UserContext". So that I can parse my header and assign the values into that and access it in Data or View Layer (for example). This will help me to avoid passing the values in every method. At the same it has to maintain life cycle for each request.

Is there anything like that in Django?

Comment: "This will help me to avoid passing the values in every method." - why is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plain answer is that django-tls (https://github.com/aino/django-tls) can make request available everywhere where you import it, and then you can just set attributes on request, request.user, or something similar.

That said, in 99% of the cases this is a bad idea, for instance if all you need it for is to avoid passing values to functions then it's extremely ill advised. You'll just make your code unreadable. If you have a lot of variables to pass around, maybe some of them need combining into some class?

Comment: @ Remco I agree with you.